# HTTP request is returns 400, but cannot throw error

Tags: post, request, try-catch, throw

Trying to use this request post function. When I run it with the correct requestBody it works fine, but if the requestBody is invalid it returns a HTTP 400 and fails, but no matter what I try to throw, or as such, the catch block never runs. Can anyone help? This is in Node and using the request package.

```
    const res = async() =>
    {
        try
        {
            const res = await request({
                method: "POST",
                url: "url",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString("base64")
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
            }, function(error, response, data)
            {
                if(response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Fell into else block!");
                    throw new Error("POST failed!");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            console.log("something went wrong!", error);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Catch block will not execute since you are throwing error from inside a callback. I will suggest to rewrite a part of code. Just pass the first parameter(the json) to the await request. console.log(res), and then decide further action.

Comment: ^ Tried this and it worked. Seems so obvious now! Thank you very much! @RinkalRohara

Answer (score 0):

Since request function returns a promise use catch method

```
const res = await request({
                method: "POST",
                url: "url",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString("base64")
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
            }, function(error, response, data)
            {
                if(response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Fell into else block!");
                    throw new Error("POST failed!");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("something went wrong!", error);
            });
```

Comment: Of course, this makes a lot of sense. Clearly, I have been quite foolish! Thank you very much!